# position of text in a link displayed as block element

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, position

i want to know whats the best way to position text inside a block element.

```
<a href="#">foo</a>
```

normal link but styled as display block with a background

```
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: #000000;
```

the text now is top left.
now the question: what the best way to get this text to example: bottom-left or bottom-right?

i prefer CSS solution without any new elements inside the A-Tag. Some opinions?

Comment: Is it not possible to set another wrapper element around the link or would you just rather not? Adding another element would make this simple enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't select content to sit along the bottom. By using padding (padding-top) you can manually make it look like ist's justified to the bottom.
so in the above example try

```
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 14px;
background: #000000;
padding-top: 86px
```

Comment: is this the best solution? i mean theres also vertical align for tables, line-height and stuff like that.

Comment: you don't really want to use tables - and no - there isnt vertical align for pure css elements.

Comment: `<table>` is inappropriate but there's no reason not to use `display: table` (other than compatibility).

Comment: @Kevin Reid    I think you put that comment in the wrong box!!

Comment: @JorgeLuisBorges I was replying to you. Based on the response to ptriek's answer I didn't think it was a useful answer on its own.

Comment: @Kevin Reid not really sure what you're on about as I've not suggested tables - but never mind, he's happy with the answer so this isn't really relevan, I'm sure its just crossed wires!

Answer (score 1):

You could also make use of display:table-cell - however, that won't work in <=IE7

http://jsfiddle.net/QU9gy/

Comment: yeah ofc :) but i need IE7 so i will use padding and text-align for it. but tx ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too.

```
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: #000000;
line-height:188px;
font-size:12px;
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
```

If you change your font-size than reduce than value from 200px :) means if you are using 18px font than line-height would be 182px so total no will be 200px;

Comment: only problem with this is if the text in the box goes onto two lines for any reason.

Comment: hmm..! than padding is the solution. but it that you won't get exact value and you need to trial and error to set your height. Even that also might give you trouble with multiple lines.

If multiple lines is the case for you than best solution as I believe is what **ptriek** gave you.

As you dont want to add any tag inside anchor than its very hard to set for multiple lines unless you use **ptriek** given solution.

Comment: a combination of line-height and padding means there is no trial and error. line-heght: 20px paddong-top: 180px = 200px for one line of text, 220px for two etc

Comment: not combination of both rather only padding. Set only top padding. something like. padding-top:80px etc.